# I accidently deleted my App delegate from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Unfortunately my AppDelegate Class got deleted and which is not available in trash also. Is there any way to create new one?

Is it okey If I create AppDelegate Myself?

Comment: copy it from another project, i dont think it's matter

Comment: Simply restore the file from either source code control, time machine backup, or some other backup. You do all of these things, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App delegate is class of **UIResponder**

so This class will be created same as you create tableViewCell or UIViewController Class.

just go to **New file**

From **Source Code** -> **IOS** -> **Cocoa Touch Class**.

Select Class **UIResponder**

Hope it will work

Comment: I have followed the same but getting error.  "The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file."

Comment: add UIApplicationDelegate and @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

Answer (score 1):

- When you delete file from your project, it could have asked you about whether to move the file to trash or to remove the reference alone.
- If you have chosen "move to trash", then the file would be at trash. If not there you have to create a new one.
- If you have chosen "remove reference", then the file would be at the same place. You can find it by locating the file in finder. Select the project folder, choose add files to your project and there you can find the correct file.